# ARIMA(1,0,0) one-step ahead prediction in R/forecast

Tags: r, time-series, arima, prediction

`Return` series with 30 observations:

```
Return <- c(0.001562791, 0.0032665211, 0.0255382847, 0.0162675127,
  -0.0200315418, 0.0072259871, -0.0062112001, -0.0003623057,
  -0.017030708, -0.00029492, -0.0133622358, 0.0035062888, 0,
  -0.0017143074, -0.0053106075, -0.0002250141, 0.0054610197,
  -0.0039618815, 0.0005990266, -0.0032239953, -0.0036865708,
  -0.0027927708, -0.0040140926, -0.0015949572, 0.0104348773,
  -0.0007525021, 0.008022536, -0.0122470444, -0.0057619568, -0.0028934765
)
```

ARIMA(1,0,0) generation with `Return[1:29]`series by `Arima` function in R (`forecast` package).

```
library("forecast")
M_Return_1_29 <- (Arima(Return[1:29], order = c(1,0,0))) 
summary(M_Return_1_29)
## ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 
## 
## Coefficients:
##           ar1  intercept
##       -0.0365    -0.0007
## s.e.   0.1836     0.0016
## 
## sigma^2 estimated as 8.776e-05:  log likelihood=95.33
## AIC=-184.66   AICc=-183.7   BIC=-180.56
## 
## Training set error measures:
##                        ME        RMSE         MAE MPE MAPE      MASE
## Training set 2.811408e-06 0.009039216 0.006242894 Inf  Inf 0.6230254
##                     ACF1
## Training set 0.001214897
```

So, when calculate one ahead prediction (prediction for 30th value for `Return`) by:`predict(M_Return_1_29,n.ahead=1)`It gives this output:

```
$pred
#Time Series:
#Start = 30 
#End = 30 
#Frequency = 1 
#[1] -0.0005256081

$se
#Time Series:
#Start = 30 
#End = 30 
#Frequency = 1 
#[1] 0.009368022
```

I would like to caculate   `-0.0005256081` by hand. But when I try this `Ŷ30  =  -0.0007  + (-0.0365*Yt29) 
= Ŷ30 = -0.0007  + (-0.0365*-0.0057619568)
= -0.0004896885768`

Note that I take `-0.0057619568 as Yt29` from the original series.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118637/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the "Details" section of `?arima` (in the base `stats` package) which `Arima()` (from `forecast`) is based on. This clarifies the parametrization of the model and shows that the `intercept` is in fact the *mean* of the response variable which differs from the *intercept* in autoregressive models. More precisely:
$$Y_t - \mu = \phi \cdot (Y_{t-1} - \mu).$$
Thus, the one-step ahead prediction is:
$$\hat Y_{t+1|t} = \hat \mu + \hat \phi \cdot (Y_t - \hat \mu).$$
In your example

```
coef(M_Return_1_29)[2] + coef(M_Return_1_29)[1] *
  (Return[29] - coef(M_Return_1_29)[2])
##     intercept 
## -0.0005256081
```

which matches the `predict()` output.

Comment: But, `#coef(M_Return_1_29)[2] + coef(M_Return_1_29)[1] *(Return[29] - coef(M_Return_1_29)[2]) = -0.000515238` Is it because of $$\hat e_{t}$$?

Comment: Note sure how you obtained this, I get `-0.0005256081`. First I thought that it was due to a missing comma in the replication code (which I just corrected in an edit) but that would have lead to even more different results...

Comment: It is because I calculate it by hand, but when I calculate by your code above by R, it is ok. Appreciated!