# Manual calculation of ARIMA(1,1,0) forecast

Tags: self-study, forecasting, arima, unit-root

I have read the questions about the `ARIMA` and `ARMA` prediction [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266828/arima1-0-0-one-step-ahead-prediction-in-r-forecast) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118637/how-to-build-a-function-with-the-result-of-auto-arima-in-r), and also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32634/difference-time-series-before-arima-or-within-arima).

I'd like to make an one-step ahead forecast in-sample with the `ARIMA(p=1,d=1,q=0)` model. I have used the `forecast` packages:

```
library(forecast)
  set.seed(1)
  n<-252
  mydata1 <- runif(n, 9000, 10000)
  fit1<-Arima(mydata1[1:(n-1)], order=c(1,1,0))
  forecast(fit1, h=1)$mean[1] 
  # 9850.593
```

Then I have tried to use the `predict()` function

```
  predict(fit1, n.ahead=1)$pred[1]
  # 9850.593
```

The reasults are equal. The `ARIMA(1,1,0)` model has only one coefficient `ar1`:

```
  fit1$coef[1]
  # ar1 
  # -0.4896545
```

I have tried to write the one-step ahead prediction:
$$\hat Y_{n|n-1} = \hat \mu + \hat{ar_1} \cdot (Y_{n-1} - \hat \mu).$$

and then make the calculation in R:

```
mean(mydata1[n-1]) + coef(fit1)[1] * (mydata1[n-1] - mean(mydata1[n-1]))
#     ar1 
# 9761.974
```

The manual result is `9761.974` and it is not equal to `9850.593`.
I think my mistake in the formula because I should use the first difference of time series (`d=1`) but not the original time series.

**Question**. Could anyone guide me in the manual calculation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ARIMA(1,1,0) model is defined as follows:
$$
(y_t - y_{t-1}) = \phi (y_{t-1} - y_{t-2}) + \varepsilon_t \,, \quad
\varepsilon_t \sim NID(0, \sigma^2) \,.
$$

The one-step ahead forecast is then (forwarding the above expression one period ahead):

$$
\hat{y}_{t+1} = \hat{y}_t + \phi (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1}) + \underbrace{E(\varepsilon_{t+1})}_{=0} \,.
$$

In your example:

```
coef(fit1)*(mydata1[n-1]-mydata1[n-2])+mydata1[n-1]
# 9850.593 
# agreeing with
predict(fit1, n.ahead=1)$pred[1]
# [1] 9850.593
```

Comment: The above was super helpful! what will it be if exogenous variables were in the mix?

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz You may be interested in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103010/) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141109/) post.